# Enlarging a path like a stroke

Tags: inkscape, text

New person here! I am messing around with logos at the moment, and I want to make the text's path bigger like making it bold. I know you can do this by duplicating an object and adding a stroke to one of them and then unite them, but the process becomes tedious especially while working with large amounts of text. Is there any way to automate this? Or is there an alternative solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use bold fonts in Inkscape, if you have a bold version of the font installed on your system.  I wouldn't recommend adding a stroke to a font to make it look bold, mainly because it usually doesn't look that good. It's no substitute for a real bold font.

By the way, you don't have to duplicate/unite anything. If you want to add a stroke to make a font look bold, you can apply it to editable text.  If you want to mess with the font outlines, or turn it to outlines for SVG output then yes, but for general use there's no need.

For other paths/shapes, there's also a possibility that you are looking for the *Path > Outset / Dynamic Offset* functions. But these don't work so well with text outlines because it will distort shapes/round the corners. However these can work well for other paths/shapes.